# El while no evalúa que la nota sea hasta 100

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Resulta que en el siguiente código, el while no evalúa que la nota sea hasta 100, para que cuando supere el porcentaje evaluada a 100 vuelva a preguntar el último porcentaje, además de calcular la nota definitiva  de acuerdo a los porcentajes de cada nota ingresada.

```
print("¡Bienvenido! En esta aplicación los estudiantes podrán gestionar las notas de su materia.")
nombre=input("Por favor ingrese su nombre: ") #solicitamos el nombre del alumno
materia=input("Ingrese el nombre de la materia: ") #solicitamos el nombre de la materia
notas=0
sumapromedio=0

while notas >=0 and notas <=100:
    notas=float(input("Ingrese la nota obtenida: ")) #solictamos al usuario las notas
    promedio=int(input("Ingrese el porcentaje de la nota: "))
    validar=input("¿Falta añadir notas? S/N: ")
    notas=notas+1
    sumapromedio+=promedio

    if sumapromedio>100:
        print("El porcentaje evaluado de una materia no puede ser mayor a 100") 
        promedio=int(input("Ingrese el porcentaje de la nota: "))
        validar=input("¿Falta añadir notas? S/N: ")
        if validar == "N" and sumapromedio=="100":
            nota_final=notas*(sumapromedio/100)
        

    
if nota_final<3:
    print(f"El Estudiante {nombre} cursó la materia {materia} y obtuvo {nota_final} resultando en no aprobado.")

    
else:
    print(f"El Estudiante {nombre} cursó la materia {materia} y obtuvo {nota_final} resultando en aprobado.")
```

Comment: No entiendo el bucle, ¿lo usas hasta que se ingrese una nota erronea? porque si es haci te queda mejor usar un while True: ... nota=int(input(....)); if nota<0 or nota>100:  break

Comment: Si quieres que pregunte por nota hasta que se ingrese una cantidad correcta debes hacer un bucle a parte para ello: while true: """Primer bucle"""; while nota<0 or nota>100: 
 nota=int(input(...));

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo encarecidamente que utilices funciones para realizar las distintas acciones como pedir notas, o porcentajes.
también te recomiendo usar matrices, o arrays para guardar las notas con cada porcentaje respectivamente.
Para el tema de evaluar que la nota sea hasta 100 yo haría lo siguiente:

```
def pedirNota(): #metodo para pedir nota
    global notas #esto hace falta para que detecte la varible global
    revisador = True #esta variable controla la salida del bucle while
    while revisador:#con este while controlamos que el usuario introduzca una nota con un valor numerico valido
        try:
            nota = float(input("Ingrese la nota obtenida: "))  # solictamos al usuario las notas
            if nota <= 100 and nota >= 0 : #aqui supongo que la nota quieres que no sea mayor de 100 ni menor de 0
                notas.append(nota) #aqui añado la nota que me acaban de meter a un array declarado como global previamente declarado
            else:
                raise NameError("La nota no puede ser menor a 0 ni mayor que 100 intentalo de nuevo")

            revisador = False
        except ValueError:
            print("La nota debe ser un numero, vuelve a intentar introducirla")
        except NameError as e:
            print(e.args[0])
    print("la nota se agrego correctamente")
```

Una función que comprueba con un try si la nota es mayor a 100 o menor a 0, si se cumple salta una excepción personalizada y hago que se vuelva a pedir la nota, de lo contrario no salta la excepción y sale del bucle

haria algo parecido para pedir los porcentajes

```
def pedirPromedio():
    global promedios #esto hace falta para que detecte la varible global
    revisador = True #esta variable controla la salida del bucle while
    while revisador:#con este while controlamos que el usuario introduzca una nota con un valor numerico valido
        try:
            print("lleva " + str(sum(promedios)) + '% de total de la asignatura, solo puede introducir hasta 100')
            porcentaje = float(input("Ingrese el porcentaje de la nota : "))  # solictamos al usuario el porcentaje
            if sum(promedios) + porcentaje <= 100 :
                promedios.append(porcentaje)
                revisador = False
            elif sum(promedios) + porcentaje >= 100:
                raise NameError("La suma de  los porcentajes no puede ser mayor a 100 introduce un porcentaje nuevo para esta nota ")

        except ValueError:
            print("El porcentaje debe ser un numero, vuelve a intentar introducirla")
        except NameError as e:
            print(e.args[0])
    print("el porcentaje se agrego correctamente")
```

una función parecida a la de las notas, entonces en el método principal vamos a llamar estas dos funciones seguido primero la de nota y seguido la del porcentaje así vamos a tener dos array ordenador con las notas y su debido porcentaje,

Para calcular la nota final teniendo en cuenta los porcentajes recorrería cada elemento de las notas con su respectivo porcentaje y haría la operación matemática para obtener el peso de cada una para la nota final, todo esto lo sumaria y tendría la nota final.
Es lo que haria yo xd.

Comment: *Te recomiendo encarecidamente que utilices funciones para realizar las distintas acciones como pedir notas, o porcentajes. también te recomiendo usar matrices, o arrays para guardar las notas* -> La pregunta es claramente sobre un ejercicio de clase, pedirle encarecidamente que use arrays o funciones cuando es muy probable que todavía ni siquiera lo haya visto en clase es más bien poco útil... Usará lo que sabe usar y lo que su profesor le ha pedido que use en su ejercicio :) Normalmente en las preguntas de clase es mejor ceñirse a lo que el usuario parece conocer.